# which tools are helpful in determining the cyclomatic complexity of a given C source code

Tags: c, complexity-theory

I want to know which tool can be used to measure the cyclomatic complexity of a C source.

I have seen other post which ask the same question but I want to know specific tool for C source only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.spinroot.com/static/

Answer (score 0):

[Locmetrics](http://www.locmetrics.com/) is a nice tool, works for C (as well as others) and will give you the McCabe cyclomatic result.

Answer (score 0):

I found out this tool is also very useful
[source monitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html)